# Add custom Js and css to admin panel Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, js-css

In

> `/magento1/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/instagramapi.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.3"> 
<adminhtml_system_config_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
           <name>instagramapi/css/hBratingsliderAdmin.min.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
             <script>instagramapi/js/jscolor/jscolor.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit>
    <default>
       <reference name="head">
    .............
```

file is located at

> `magento1/skin/adminhtml/default/default/instagramapi/js/jscolor/jscolor.js`

and

> `/magento1/skin/adminhtml/default/default/instagramapi/css/hBratingsliderAdmin.min.css`

is there any error in this code as no css or js file is included in admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.3">
<adminhtml_system_config_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
           <type>skin_css</type>
           <name>instagramapi/css/hBratingsliderAdmin.min.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
             <type>js</type>
             <name>instagramapi/js/jscolor/jscolor.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit>
```

Also you should put your `instagramapi.xml` file at location

> /magento1/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/instagramapi.xml

Comment: Not working sir

Comment: can you add path of your js and css files?

Comment: which path sir ,these files are not included

Comment: where did you put this js&css files which you want to include?

Comment: ok i updated my post

Comment: not working yet

Comment: change you layout file path as in my answer, also make sure that you have declared admin layout in config.xml file

Comment: OK , i understood my mistake, i was updating frontend layout

Comment: Thank you SIR, you are great , from last 2 days your answer always helped me .